# setup Google Analytics 4 in nuxt.js

Tags: google-analytics, nuxt.js, google-analytics-4

I'm having issues setting up a new Google Analytics 4 (GA4) account with Nuxt.  Everything seems configured ok based on tutorials, however my traffic doesn't show up in GA (dev & production)

In nuxt.config.js I have the following

```
  buildModules: [
    '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss','@nuxtjs/google-analytics'
  ],
  googleAnalytics: {
    id: 'G-HWW3B1GM6W'
  },
```

The google id is a GA4 Data Stream id with my production website.  I tried 2 different streams, with www and without, but the traffic doesn't show up in GA4.

Comment: @nuxtjs/google-analytics only accepts Universal Analytics IDs which is officially being done away with by Google and in addition the author of @nuxtjs/google-analytics no longer supports the module and recommends switching to vue-gtag. 

The issue with that is that vue-gtag requires Vue 3 which is not currently available in a stable version of Nuxt.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

**[UPDATE]**

If you want to use GA4 Property (which is what has the ids in the format G-XXXXXXXXXX) you can try to use [vue-gtag](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag) package by creating a plugin:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag'

Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: { id: 'G-XXXXXXXXXX' }
})
```

Add this in nuxtconfig.js

```
plugins: ['@/plugins/gtag']
```

---

About the problem indicated in your message, that plugin you mentioned works with the Universal version of Google Analytics (which is what has the ids in the format `UA-XXXXXXXXX-X`), like the example in your link:

```
 buildModules: [
   '@nuxtjs/tailwindcss','@nuxtjs/google-analytics'
 ],
 googleAnalytics: {
   id: 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X'
 },
```

The code you entered in the example, `G-HWW3B1GM6W`, refers to the new Google Analytics 4 which, being a different system from the previous one and does not work (yet) with that plugin.

So I suggest you to create a Universal Analytics type Property and use its ID (UA-XXXXX-X) with the plugin you indicated. You can find it by clicking on `Show advanced options` (when you create a new property):

[image]

Comment: Hi! Do you know if installing this way will allow route tracking? Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: vue-gtag has a hard requirement of Vue3 which is not available in a stable version of Nuxtjs (yet).  If you are using Nuxt v2 this approach won't work.

Comment: if you're on Nuxt v2, you can install vue-gtag v1 and it works just fine...

`npm install vue-gtag@1 --save`

Comment: As this is mostly only needed on the client (in production) you can check `if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "production")` in your Plugin & and configure the `mode` plugin option in your array of Plugins in `nuxt.config.js` as `{ src: "@/plugins/g-analytics.js", mode: "client" }`

Answer (score 26):

You can use `vue-gtag` [package](https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag) by creating a plugin.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueGtag from 'vue-gtag'

Vue.use(VueGtag, {
  config: { id: 'G-XXXXXXXXXX' }
})
```

Remember to add it in nuxtconfig.js

```
plugins: ['@/plugins/gtag']
```

Comment: Thank you! Don't forget to disable the tag on localhost

Comment: ^ for prod only pass { enable: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' }

Comment: @ihorbond - Isn't it `enabled`, rather than `enable`?  https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/plugin-options

Answer (score 25):

I had the same problem, and I solved it by just using the vanilla JavaScript:

*/static/js/ga.js*

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
gtag('js', new Date());

gtag('config', 'G-XXXXXXXXXX');
```

*/nuxt.config.js*

```
export default {
    head: {
        script: [
            {
                src: "https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=G-XXXXXXXXXX",
                async: true,
            },
            {
                src: "js/ga.js",
            }
        ]
    },
}
```

Comment: A good solution if you don't want to use and manage yet another third-party plugin. Worked for my site.

Comment: This solution works best considering all these vue ga packages keep deprecating

Comment: the code in /static/js/ga.js can just be added as callback: option of the script, no need for a separate file

Comment: For "vue-meta": "^2.4.0" I had to add the `hid` property alongside the `callback` option. If not the later was not getting called.

Comment: @ihor.eth Could you post code as a callback option of script?

Comment: @sandalwoodsh here https://vue-meta.nuxtjs.org/api/#callback

Comment: Does anyone know a way to include the code of ga.js inline, without a separate file?

Answer (score 2):

I found this way more simpler with Nuxt 3, Vue 3 and Google analytics 4.

First you will need to add this latest plugin for vue-gtag

`npm add --dev vue-gtag-next`

Then create a plugin file `plugins/vue-gtag.client.js`

In this file, add this code

```
import VueGtag, { trackRouter } from 'vue-gtag-next'
export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  nuxtApp.vueApp.use(VueGtag, {
    property: {
      id: 'GA_MEASUREMENT_ID'
    }
  })
  trackRouter(useRouter())
})
```

You can also use optin/optout feature if you want to disable that plugin at any time using `isEnabled` flag.

https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/v/next/opt-in-out

Here is the link to documentation.

https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/plugins#vue-plugins

https://matteo-gabriele.gitbook.io/vue-gtag/v/next/

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me, when using the regular `vue-gtag` make sure to use `config` instead of `property`

Answer (score 1):

I came here since I had no results in GA when I was in development or production mode.

The **first thing you need to do** is to disable any AdBlockers or Anti-trackers for the website you want to test.

**Secondly**, you need to be in production mode (`npm run build` and then `npm start`).

If you wish to be in development mode and still get results in GA then pass`debug: { sendHitTask: true }` in the GA configuration inside nuxt.config.js:

```
publicRuntimeConfig: {
    googleAnalytics: {
      id: process.env.GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_ID,
      debug: {
        sendHitTask: true
      }
    }
 },
```