# Can I use Vue-analytics with a Measurement ID?

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've been looking for a way to easily integrate Google Analytics and Tag manager to a VueJS project I'm working on. I came across the solution of using a library called vue-analytics for this, but the tutorials I've seen always talk about setting it up with a Tracking ID, that looks like: UA-XXXXXX-X, which I don't have, I have a Measurement ID, that looks like: G-XXXXXXX.

So I was wondering if there's any difference with using either with Vue-analytics, and if there is, is it better that I get a Tracking ID or is there a way to set it up with a Measurement ID?

Thanks so much for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [setup Google Analytics 4 in nuxt.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64612031/setup-google-analytics-4-in-nuxt-js)